# FreeDOS reboot command

Tags: boot, reboot

I have pre-installed on my computer a copy of `FreeDOS`.

I looked through the help, but did not found any commands for rebooting the computer.

Also, searching through Google yielded some not so useful commands. (By this I mean not existing) .

It the `0.27` version, I think.

Answer (score 3):

**fdapm [Options]**

*Options*

**WARMboot**  Do a reboot without BIOS tests (POST). Usually safe but can
            crash if you use incompatible protected mode software, like
            some versions of EMM386. Flushes the disk caches before
            rebooting.
 **COLDboot**  Do a reboot with BIOS tests (POST) (after flushing the disk
            caches) by telling the 8042 keyboard controller to pulse
            the hardware reset circuits. Very similar to a real cold
            reboot - only in rare cases, pressing the reset button or
            power-cycling the computer will give you a "colder" reset.

***fdapm coldboot***

[Fdapm instructions](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/fdapm.htm)

Comment: **fdapm coldboot**  **UPDATED**